# In Highchart legend, the label color is the same with the color of shape

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I wish the label color in legend item (Highchart) is the same with the color of corresponding shape (in this case, the shape is a line) in legend, and the line doesn't be displayed.

Refer below image for more description.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use workaround with linked series, which has defined no marker.

```
series: [{
        color: 'red',
        marker: {
            enabled: false
        },

    }, {
        color: 'red',
        data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6],
        linkedTo: ':previous'
    }]
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/fvvdsfw2/5/

Comment: "itemHiddenStyle" in your example can't correctly work, the item "Series 1" always is displayed in red.

Comment: It doesnt work, because we overlap styles by html object in the legend formatter. You can catch [legendItemClick](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.events.legendItemClick) and update your span with series name.